# Forge modding - Error: Unable to load definition cc:range_block#normal

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently following Mr. Crayfish'es tutorials on how to make a Minecraft mod for Minecraft 1.8 with Forge. I've followed what he is doing, but Forge is:

```
Unable to load definition cc:range_block#normal
```

---

**The whole error message** looks like this:

```
[18:05:29] [Client thread/WARN]: Unable to load definition cc:range_block#normal
java.lang.RuntimeException: Encountered an exception when loading model definition of 'cc:range_block#normal' from: 'cc:blockstates/range_block.json' in resourcepack: 'FMLFileResourcePack:Cooking Craft'
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelBakery.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:167) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelBakery.loadVariants(ModelBakery.java:118) [ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadBlocks(ModelLoader.java:96) [ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:69) [ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:29) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:124) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:470) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:325) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:117) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:78) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:45) [start/:?]
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 4 column 6
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:56) ~[Streams.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:54) ~[TreeTypeAdapter.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:741) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.parseFromReader(ModelBlockDefinition.java:35) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelBakery.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:162) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 4 column 6
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505) ~[JsonReader.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:494) ~[JsonReader.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:403) ~[JsonReader.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:666) ~[TypeAdapters$25.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:667) ~[TypeAdapters$25.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:642) ~[TypeAdapters$25.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:44) ~[Streams.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:54) ~[TreeTypeAdapter.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:741) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.parseFromReader(ModelBlockDefinition.java:35) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelBakery.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:162) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    ... 16 more
```

---

**I've added the block to the `GameRegistry`** with `GameRegistry.registerBlock(Block, String)`, and registered the block renderer with this code:

```
// Get the block item
Item blockItem = Item.getItemFromBlock(block);
// Register the block
Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(blockItem, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(ModData.MOD_ID + ":" + blockItem.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5), "inventory"));
```

The `ModData.MOD_ID` variable is a `String` whose value is equal to `"cc"`.

---

**The project structure** looks like this:

[image]

---

The *model*, *item* and *blockstate* files contains this code:

*blockstates/range_block.json*:

```
{
    "variants": {
        "normal": { "model": "cc:range_block" },
    }
}
```

*models/block/range_block.json*:

```
{
    "parent": "block/orientable",
    "textures": {
        "top": "cc:blocks/range_block_top",
        "front": "cc:blocks/range_block_front_off",
        "side": "cc:blocks/range_block_side"
    }
}
```

*models/item/range_block.json*:

```
{
    "parent": "cc:block/range_block",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson": {
            "rotation": [ 10, -45, 170 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.5, -2.75 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**I've got it working far enough to see the textures applied to the block in the inventory**, but when I place it, I see the cyan-black texture for blocks which is missing textures.

I'm relatively new to Forge (1.8), so I haven't really understood everything yet, but I'm on my way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... The solution to this problem was simple, but hard to find. I had to change the first line in the *models/block/range_block.json* file:

```
"parent": "block/orientable"
```

to:

```
"parent": "minecraft:block/orientable"
```

In other words, tell Forge that the `block/orientable` file is in the minecraft directory.